# Importing large data regularly in sql server

Tags: sql-server, import, bigdata

We have an application that uses SQL Server and needs to be refreshed with a source system's data at a regular interval. There are millions of records in the source system and we refresh it every 30 mins. We are currently using openquery and cursors to import the data and keep it fresh. However, this approach seems time consuming and not very reliable.

Does anyone know any other options we can use?

Also, for some source tables, there are hooks like last modified datetime etc...that we can use to get smaller chunks of data since it was last modified. But it isn't very reliable either as that field doesn't seem to get updated every time and also is not the case with all the tables. So, it is really a pain to deal with the ones that don't have hooks like this.

Do you think we could use big data solutions like Hadoop, MapReduce etc... in anyway? My impression about these was that they are useful in storing and fetching legacy data and/or fetching bigger data like when dealing with files. Not sure how they'd come into play in just importing table data.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's an idea.  http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/bulk-insert-example-using-an-idatareader-to-strong-dataset-to-sql-server-xml/

Comment: Is the goal to continue to use SQL and use some other system on top or are you interested in jumping out of SQL? I guess I'm asking because te biggest reason to use relational databases is their ACID properties, I guess the second biggest is existing infrastructure and expertise.

If you take out the ACID properties many other platforms will provide lighter weight solutions, that provide better availability. It's a question more of what your specific requirements are and the scope of changes you are ready to understake.

Comment: I think the requirement right now is more availability and we can abandon SQL oriented solutions given that it doesn't take up way too much memory and is transaction oriented. We once exposed the source system data using a webservice and transactions but that didn't help much.

Comment: Does the source system support triggers? You could add a trigger to each table you are interested in to either update your own 'lastmodified' field or post messages with rowid (but this has side issues). This would let you identify the subset to apply.

Comment: we only have read only access to the source system.